# GraphicsBoxOptions no longer working in Mathematica 13.3

Tags: options, stylesheet

Previously, I used `GraphicsBoxOptions` to set `BaseStyles` for my notebook. It is no longer working in Mathematica 13.3. What is the solution in replacement?

For example, how do I update the following cell in my notebook stylesheet?

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
  GraphicsBoxOptions -> {
    BaseStyle -> {PointSize -> Absolute[4], Thickness -> Absolute[1.5], ImageSizeRaw->{{180}, {180}}}
]
```

Comment: I took a quick look at the Core.nb stylesheet in the installation directory under SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets. If I search for GraphicsBoxOptions, I see at least two entries that use DefaultBaseStyle instead of BaseStyle. You might give that a try.